# Javascript string object readonly? 

Tags: javascript, string, readonly

```
a=new String("Hello");
```

[image: String("Hello")]

```
a[0]==="H" //true
a[0]="J"
a[0]==="J" //false
a[0]==="H" //true
```

Does this mean I can only use Strings as arrays of char's by `.split("")` and then `.join("")`?

---

**ANSWER:** Yes, in `Javascript strings are readonly` (aka immutable) This question is answered here at:

- [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)
- [What does immutable mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200211/what-does-immutable-mean)

Comment: for all intensive purposes, for all I can see is that new String("hello") is virtually equivilant to just "hello". It has no extra array methods etc, and can be manipulated only through the same methods. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: @PlacidCow it does have [] to get individual characters though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#JavaScript), so yes. `a` should be reassigned if you want to change the string. You can also use `slice`: `a = 'j'+a.slice(1)`, or a `replace`: `a = a.replace(/^h/i,'j')`.

You could create a custom mutable `String` object, something like [this experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/k7kuc/) (esp. see method `replaceCharAt`).

Answer (score 3):

Thats correct.

You can of course build a function to handle this for you.

See this SO Post for different examples of this:

[How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If it is necessary to be able to perform manipulations on your string as if it were an array or chars, that you perhaps create some prototypes:

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start,length,insert) {
    var a = this.slice(0, start);
    var b = this.slice(start+length, this.length);
    if (!insert) {insert = "";};
    return new String(a + insert + b);
};

String.prototype.push = function(insert) {
    var a = this
    return new String(a + insert);
};

String.prototype.pop = function() {
    return new String(this.slice(0,this.length-1));
};

String.prototype.concat = function() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        var string = "";
        for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            string += arguments[i];
        };
        return new String(this + string);
    };
};

String.prototype.sort = function(funct) {
    var arr = [];
    var string = "";
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        arr.push(this[i]);
    };
    arr.sort(funct);
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        string += arr[i];
    };
    return new String(string);
};

var a = new String("hello");
var b = a.splice(1,1,"b");
var c = a.pop();
var d = a.concat(b,c);
var e = a.sort();
```

returns hello,
hbllo,
hell, hellohbllohell, ehllo

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I was asking whether Javascript strings were readonly, all your answers are using a new string to replace the old one.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't the .valueOf() method of the Strings prototype return its primitive value ?
Like,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically string in javascript are differentiated by two types one is primitive and another is object . String objects are character sequences .

You can use primitive type of string .

```
   var x = "hello";

   console.log(x);

     output : "hello"
    x = "j"+x.substring(1);
    console.log(x);
    output : "jello";
```

Or use

```
  var x = new String("hello");
  console.log(x.toString());
  x = "j"+x.substring(1);
```