# JavaScript toUpperCase isn't working. Why?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple function. To turn all words first-letter to upper case, but It simply doesn't work, neither display any errors:

```js
function formatTitle(input) {
  var words = input.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i][0] = words[i][0].toUpperCase();
  };
  return words.join(' ');
};

var newTitle = formatTitle("all words first-letter should be upper case");

document.write(newTitle);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fancy ES6 approach: `[...words[i]].map((a,b)=>!b?a.toUpperCase():a).join('');`.

Comment: @Xufox The fancy ES6 approach is much heavier than a fancy regex approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that strings in javascript are immutable. You can't just change a char like this.

A solution would be this:

```
words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase()+words[i].slice(1);
```

But you could have a simpler and faster code using a regular expression:

```
return input.replace(/\b\w/g,function(b){ return b.toUpperCase() })
```

(here with a more complete uppercasing, not just after spaces - if you want to stick to spaces use `replace(/(\s+|^)\w/g,function(b){ return b.toUpperCase() })`)

Comment: I'll go with the first approach. Using `regex` is bit slower than `string` methods

Comment: "Using regex is bit slower" ? Most of the times using a regex is a bigger improvement in performances compared to string and array manipulations (maybe not here due to function calling, we'd need to test, unfortunately jsperf.com is down).

Comment: @Tushar I verified: using a regex here, even the complex one, is much faster http://jsbin.com/zohikoxubo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: You can also “prove” that strings are immutable with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(words[i],0).writable == false`.

Answer (score 6):

**Problem**

Because

```
words[i][0] = 'something'
```

does not update the `words[i]`.

**Problem Demo**

```js
var myVar = 'abc';

myVar[0] = 'd';

document.write(myVar); // abc
```

**Solution**

You can use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the first character and update the value of whole string.

**Solution Demo**

```js
function formatTitle(input) {
  var words = input.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
  }
  return words.join(' ');
}

var newTitle = formatTitle("all words first-letter should be upper case");

document.write(newTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

How wrote Denis the reason is that strings in javascript are immutable (numbers and booleans are also immutable).

Another very simple solution for Upperize the first char of a string is:

```
function firstUpper(word) {
     return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
};
```

I suggest also to read this post: [Understanding Javascript immutable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115512/understanding-javascript-immutable-variable)

Hope this help