# Angular js scope on nested template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive where I have been using as

```
<ui-submit-button btn-state='btnSendProcessing' />
```

The `btnSendProcessing` is a value in the controller's scope it gets turned on and off while the http request is being fired.

The `ng-disabled` works but it is not showing the processing icon.

```
.directive('uiSubmitButton', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template : function() {
        return ' \
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-disabled="btnState"> \
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="btnState" /> {{btnState}} \
            <i class="fa fa-cog" ng-show="btnState" /> \
            <span ng-hide="btnState">{{btnLabel || "Submit"}}</span> \
          </button>';
      },
      replace : true,
      scope : {
        btnState : '=',
        btnLabel : '@'
      }
    };

  })
```

What could be the issue here?

Fiddle is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/to5y9kud/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/to5y9kud/1/

Comment: Could be that in your app you're messing up the scope because you're exposing a primitive variable from the controller. So try and add something like a settings object: scope.settings = {loading: false}. Then bind to that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in scope inheritance, and basically in any js prototype inheritance, if you use a primitive, it copies the primitive value to the inherited object.

if you want changes to effect both the parent and the inherited scope, you should use an Array or an Object, this is an example which explains what is a normal behavior of an inherited scope:

```
$parentScope.a = 1;
$parentScope.b = {a:1};
$childScope = $parentScope.$new() //inherit from $parentScope

console.log($childScope.a === 1, $childScope.b.a === 1) //true, true
$childScope.a = 2;
$childScope.b.a = 2;
console.log($parentScope.a === 2, $parentScope.b.a === 2) //false, true
```

so in your case `btnSendProcessing` should be an object and not a primitive. here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avp9ye1g/1/

read this great answer for better understanding: [Understanding Javascript immutable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115512/understanding-javascript-immutable-variable);

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, the fiddle was already working with the primitive data type boolean, it's just not working on my application.

Comment: also when you change it from a primitive to a Object?

Comment: testing it now, I wonder thought how is it that ng-show for example works with primitive values