# Eloquent JavaScript : immutable string values

Tags: javascript, string, variables, constants, immutability

Eloquent JavaScript says string values are immutable, as the first Stackoverflow question's answer : [Understanding Javascript immutable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115512/understanding-javascript-immutable-variable)

But if we write the following : `var string = "hello world"; string = "permitted";`, the string is really modified.

The answer I mentionned above just explain that objects are mutable, not the other values.

Since the string can be modified as I told you just above, does it mean that the string primitive value is automatically converted into an object when it succeeds a '=' ?

So the previous code would be strictly equivalent to : `var string = new String("hello world"); string = new String("permitted")`. That would explain why the string's value is modified.

Comment: You can overwrite the variable, but you can't change the string, for instance `string.replace(something)` creates a new string, it **can not** modify the string because it's *immutable*.

Comment: But you aren't modifying the string. You're just assigning a new string to that variable.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : yes, I agree with you. Does it really occures ?

Comment: @adeneo : so there isn't any conversion string->String instance ?

Comment: "immutable" means the value of the string can't be changed, it does not mean you can't just assign a different value to the variable. String methods do not change the original string, they just create a new string.

Comment: On the surface it may appear modified, but if you compared the original string and new string, the new string object doesn't have old string's properties.

Comment: So there is a conversion : the primitive value is converted to an object no ?

Comment: @adeneo : I think I understand. You're telling me there isn't conversion no ?

Comment: `new String` is a *reference* to a copy of primitive.

Comment: try yourself var s = "hello world"; 
var r = s;

console.log(s === r);

s = "permitted";

console.log(s === r);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between reassignment and mutation:

```js
let x = "abc";

x = "123"; // reassignment
console.log(x);

x[0] = "9"; // mutation
console.log(x);
```

After the mutation `x` still contains `"123"`, because `String`s are immutable. If `String`s were mutable it would contain `"912"` of course.

You must also distinguish between the following terms:

- Variable

With this declaration `let x = "abc"` you declare a variable `x` and initialize it with the value `"abc"`.

- Identifier

Whenever `x` is used in your code (except when declaring) it is just an identifier and have to be bound to the corresponding variable declaration  by Javascript. Please note that you can have several declarations like `let x = "abc"` in different scopes and hence name binding is necessary:

```js
let x = "abc";

{ // another scope
  let x = "123";

  { // and yet another scope
    console.log(x); // which is the corresponding variable of this identifier?
  }
}
```

If you want to prevent that a variable can be reassigned, you can actually do this in ES2015:

```
const x = "abc";
x = "123"; // throws an Error
```

Notice that you modified the variable declaration to achieve this behavior.

Comment: When you say "`String`"s are immutable, you're speaking about the primitive value or about the object ? (because in JS, these both values exist)

Comment: @Lern-X A string `Object` is merely a `String` primitive wrapped in an `Object`: `let x = new String("abc")`. The `String` primitive is still immutable `x[0] = "x"` yields `"abc"`, but the wrapper isn't: `x.prop = true; x.prop` yields `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a demonstration will show you what it means for a string to be immutable.

```js
var stringobject = new String("test"); // or "test"; both yield same result
console.assert(stringobject.valueOf() === "test", "before");

stringobject[0] = "T"; // replace first char
console.assert(stringobject.valueOf() === "Test", "after");

console.log("Success?"); // or is it?
```