# Why should template expressions return the same reference on repeated invocation?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular 2 recommends that template expressions be idempotent according to the following [definition](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions):

> If the expression returns an object (including an Array), it returns the same object **reference** when called twice in a row.

What does angular care about the identity of that object? Put differently, what can happen if a template expression returns a new object with the same contents instead?

Comment: May be the function called only once by the parser? Avoiding loops and unnecessary processes?

Comment: I don't think it's related with angular; It's related with object immutability. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115512/understanding-javascript-immutable-variable

Comment: See also https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487#.6jn19d73g

Comment: For Angular change detection to work Angular needs to know, what changed. It does a strict equality comparison and for objects its matching the reference. If you return a new object with same content, in production mode Angular change detection will not complain, but it development mode, Angular will log a warning in browser console.