# JS - overwrite this in prototype function

Tags: javascript

I want to overwrite *this* in Number prototype function and dynamically change the value of variable, for example:

```
Number.prototype.xd = function(){
  this = 11212;
}
var a = 171717;
console.log(a);
a.xd();
console.log(a);
```

is what I want, but it throws an error.
In this way works Array.prototype.pop method:

```
fruits = ["a","b","c","d"];
console.log(fruits);
fruits.pop();
console.log(fruits);
```

Can I do the same?

Comment: Have you ever noticed that all methods for primitive values *return* a new value?

Comment: `Array.prototype.pop` doesn't assign to `this`, it modifies the properties of the object that `this` refers to.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot achieve what you want because numbers in JS are immutable.

Another reason why this wouldn't work is because `this` is already dynamic in JS by its definition so it will automatically change every time a function is called, depending on how it's called.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. The `number` is one of JS primitives and as [all primitives](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/) it wraps into `Number` in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify complex types (object, array, function), but unfortunately you can't change primitive types (string, number, boolean, null, undefined). This property is referred to as "immutability".

You may also find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115543/3236521